# .Net remoting setup - Not working after 1st request

Tags: .net, memory, remoting, worker-process

I am trying to setup .Net remoting on Windows 2012 R2. The original code was in .Net 2.0, which is now migrated to .Net 4.7. Previous version of the OS was 2003. 
We have thick client application connecting to .net remoting hosted on IIS. we have enabled secure connection(https) via SSL. 
My problem is weird. First server request is processing fine(return code 200 in IIS log) and the second request will be in hung state forever, We can see that worker process is hung at ExecuteRequestHandler status. No error anywhere. But I have to do IISreset for IIS to work again and again it stops working on 1st call.

Any help will be appreciated

I believe it is all about web.config. However I have no idea how first call is working

As explained in problem statement, remoting call is expected to bring database result set

Comment: Are there any additional log files or error messages?

Comment: Unfortunately no error anywhere. That is why it has become very difficult to debug